# mixing two characters using css and drawing circle

Tags: html, css

I want to write ap graphics inside a circle. The circle is not full but like 30 %. I have wrote AP graphics inside a responsive quarter circle. The code I wrote is.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
    AP Graphis
</title>
<style>
    .quarter{
    position: relative;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    background: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="quarter" style="color: white;"><br>&nbsp;<u>AP GRAPHICS</u></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But I could not make it like the image below. Also I dont know how to mix the a and p from AP. I also dont know the font of text. I am new to css and dont know a stuff about it.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to get the svg file of the graphics and the embed it into the html page instead of redrawing the whole thing into css

Comment: Will that be responsive or not?

Comment: yes, it will be responsive as long as you set its CSS properly by using media queries. OR using bootstrap framework, only if i set the class `img` and `img-responsive` it will be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web developers dont usually create all the graphics again in css. Instead, they just use the graphics created by graphic designers into the HTML pages.

**Solution 1:**
Export the graphic (e.g., a logo) into a JPEG, or PNG file and then use it into your HTML page (using css or html `img` tag).

**Solution 2:**
If you want high quality and efficient solution, export the graphic into a vector file (e.g., an SVG file) and then use it into your web page. This involves two following steps:

Step 2.1: Exporting graphics into a vector file: Open the graphic designing software (Adobe Illustrator, CorelDRAW), and then try to `export as` into `svg` (for Adobe Photoshop, follow [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html#discontinue-export-as-svg)).

Step 2.2: Import vector file into the webpage: [see MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web)

Comment: Thanks for help. Your solution is much easier

Answer (score 1):

```css
   body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .container {
                width: 25rem;
                height: 25rem;
                border-top-right-radius: 0;
                border-top-left-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                background: orange;
                display: flex;
            }
            .quarter {
                text-decoration: underline;
                color: white;
                font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
                    "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans",
                    "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
                margin-top: 8rem;
                margin-left: 4rem;
            }
            .quarter span {
                margin-left: -1.2rem;
            }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <h1 class="quarter">
                <span>
                    <span>A</span>
                    <span>P</span>
                </span>
                GRAPHICS
            </h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer.